# Application Startup Failure with Json read Error

Tags: json, asp.net-core

This was suppose to an easy fix, it however proving very elusive. I keep getting the error

```
An error occurred while starting the application.JsonReaderException: Invalid property identifier character: {. Path '', line 2, position 2.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseProperty()FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '2': '{{'.Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(bool reload) JsonReaderException: Invalid property identifier character: {. Path '', line 2, position 2.
```

I working on an .net core web app. I have two web apps in the same solution. I moved the appsettins file from the working Web app to the one giveing the problem and the situation is still the same.
Cant figure out what I am missing

below is my appsettings.json file

```
{
  "Data": {
    "UserDbConn": {
      "connString": "Server=DbServer;Database=BookDB;    Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  },
    "Logging": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is that space between `BookDB` and `Trusted_Connection` just spaces or some kind of unreadable white-space characters?

Comment: Thats just a formatting issue. The actual code doesnt contain that space

Comment: I solved similar error by looking in the connection string there was something like this `servername\instancename`. then I replaced it with this `servername\\instancename` and problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem. In my case, I'd started implementing app secrets but left it halfway through. My `secrets.json` file was left linked but with invalid JSON.

Check your `.csproj` to see if a `<UserSecretId>` property is set under `<PropertyGroup>`. If it's set, `BuildWebHost()` will look through your `secrets.json` file in `'%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\{secretId}'`, in addition to your `appsettings.json` file. An error in either file will cause the method to fail, but it won't tell you which file it is.

The solutions in my case were either to remove the `<UserSecretId>` property or