# Could not parse the JSON file ,Error in Progam.cs asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, exception

I have some issues with the program.cs file, with the version of ASP.NetCORE 2.0

Here's my code

```
     public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseConfiguration(new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build())
            .Build();

}
```

When I run the project, following error occurs.

```
System.FormatException: 'Could not parse the JSON file. Error on line number '0': ''.'
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: What's the JSON you want to parse?

Comment: I don't know , I just wanna run project .NET core and system throw exception like this 
Does you have any idea to fix ?

Comment: Probably you add configuration files in the Startup class. Take a look there.

Comment: I checked debug in startup file but it throw exception before pass startup file

Comment: Probably the file is missing, since the error is on line 0.

Comment: I have resolve it ,thanks guys

Comment: @Runan Ngô Can you share how you resolved it?

Comment: Yes, please share your answer, I'm having the same problem.

Comment: An empty file gives this problem, it has to consist of {} at the least.

Comment: The answer is that your `secrets.json` file must have been totally empty. There should at least be opening and closing braces as in `{}` or else it will throw error as it will not be a valid json file if empty. I wasted too much time too but finally figured it out, thanks to comment of @FrodeNilsen comment above

Comment: I had similar problem, and the problem was the ',' "GoogleReCaptcha". So silly.

Answer (score 37):

Is your `appSettings.json` file (or whatever config you are using) formatted properly? `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` will not be able to parse it correctly if there are invalid characters at the start. I saw this issue when a copy/paste added a space at the beginning of the file.

Comment: I have appsettings.Test.json file and it was empty. The error disappeared after I added empty {} to the JSON settings file. Thank you!

Comment: I made a console app and crashed into this error. 
In short: Thanks!
Made an empty appsettings.json, I was only using local.settings.json.

Comment: I had an extra comma (,) at the end of a line somewhere...that post saved me!

Answer (score 29):

I had a a similar problem as this in another thread and posted my solution over there: [Application Startup Failure with Json read Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295658/application-startup-failure-with-json-read-error/51273633). Posting it here as well in case it disappears.

---

I came across the same problem. In my case, I'd started implementing app secrets but left it halfway through. My `secrets.json` file was left linked but with invalid JSON.

Check your `.csproj` to see if a `<UserSecretId>` property is set under `<PropertyGroup>`. If it's set, `BuildWebHost()` will look through your `secrets.json` file in `'%APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets\{secretId}'`, in addition to your `appsettings.json` file. An error in either file will cause the method to fail, but it won't tell you which file it is.

The solutions in my case were either to remove the `<UserSecretId>` property or

Comment: what a legend!!! I migrated to AWS Secret Manager and just cleared out my secrets file.....

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've just cleared out my secrets.json. Leaving a pair of curly braces `{}` solved it.

Comment: Amazing. The same exact thing happened to me. <3 u guys and stackoverflow

Answer (score 14):

There is a possibility it might happen when appsettings.json is not properly formated

In my case, I had the below configuration and got the error

```
 {
"ConnectionStrings": {
"TransferDBConnection": 
 "Server=INGBTCPIC5DT04D;Database=TransferDB;Trusted_Connection=true;
 },
  ***{***
   "Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
   }
 },
 "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

ideally, it should be one extra { cause this problem

```
 {
 "ConnectionStrings": {
 "TransferDBConnection": 
 "Server=INGBTCPIC5DT04D;Database=TransferDB;Trusted_Connection=true;"
 },
  "Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Same problem and solved by **removing** `<UserSecretsId> </UserSecretsId>` from `*.cproj`.

**It was a bad user secret configuration**

Comment: This was a great lead for my issue. Somehow the _secrets.json_ file was blank for the failing project. My solution was to add `{}` to my _secrets.json_ file. To edit the file, right-click on the project within the Solution Explorer and select Manage User Secrets.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with one of my complex API's, sadly I've wasted few hours to find the issue.

**First of all check whether your `appsettings.json` is well formatted as a standard JSON.**

My issue was I've mistakenly typed some characters in the appsettings.json file like this, ( for me, 'ttings' characters cause this problem)

[image]

Also check whether all your `json` files are not empty. A standard `json` should at least have two curly braces.

Comment: In my case i had empty appsettings.production.json file. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and the reason is that for some reason Visual Studio saves files with some invisible metadata that goes before the text therefore JSON reader cannot parse it.

You need to `File -> Save As -> (Choose UTF-8 Without BOM)`.

Comment: that was the solution in my case :) thanks

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had faced this issue as I had added User Secret to my solution and later removed all of its content including { }. Please make sure the content in the file is with proper JSON format. Or try providing an empty object { } to the file if no information needed from it.

Comment: This is my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I found that this problem seemed to have been caused by my `appsettings.json` file.
I copied a version from another place to solve this problem.

Comment: While this is not an answer, Please use comment section to ask additional or supplementary question. Thanks.

Comment: @ShanteshwarInde I disagree. The answer explains that copying the file from somewhere else appears to solve the problem which is a valid answer.

Comment: I also had a problem with my appsettings.json. Or more speciflcally, with my appsettings.production.json, which overlays the appsettings.json for the production build of my software. Earlier, my appsettings.production.json had curly braces with nothing in them as content. I had accidentally removed those curly braces, thinking an empty file would work too. It didn't. I didn't find out until I was deploying, because my appsettings.development.json *did* have correct content. Lesson learned: have empty braces in your overlaying appsettings files.

Comment: Thank you Jay!  I messed things up when creating new environments and their appsettings.{environmentName}.json files were empty files.  Added the curly braces to each file and it worked like a charm.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

in m case I put extra **{ right before (above)** `"ConnectionStrings" :` in appsettings.json

I copied this from another file and assumed that `"ConnectionStrings" :` must inside a curly braces {}

**before**

```
...
},
{  //<-- this one the culprit
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "Dapper": "Server=.;Database=Dapper;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    },
```

**after**

```
...
},
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "Dapper": "Server=.;Database=Dapper;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have any hidden spaces or tabs in your json. 
You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to verify your json format.

Answer (score 0):

Check your appsettings.json file. that problem is because your file doesn't have a comma,brackets, Curly brackets or another punctuation sign.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This issue could come if your appsetting.json is not well-formatted.

In my case somehow I'd an unwanted character in my appsettings.json

If you see carefully in sdk section I've got an extra l that only was causing the exception.

```
{
    "AppSettings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "ProdConnection",
        "DoGoogleAnalytics": "false"
    }, 
    "sdk": {l
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "LocalConnection": "data source=DATA_SERVER\\SQLEXPRESS,12345;initial catalog=DATABASE_NAME;persist security info=True;user id=db_user_id;password=db_password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issues was a missing comma ',' after ConnectionString curly brackets in my appsettings.json. My appsettings.json was not properly formatted. So I only had to add the comma and that was it.

"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(local); Integrated Security= true; Database = PharmDataDB; MultipleActiveResultSet=true;"
}

Answer (score -1):

for me, it was missing comma in appsettings.json

Answer (score -3):

Just place ConnectionStrings in appsetting file then run the migration command.

Comment: Please provide quality answers until you can write comments. This is not enough for an answer.